# iPhone App login Data or Session

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to create a Chat Messenger for my chat website (because of Push notifications).
But the user has to log in. I want to have it like the Facebook app, that at the beginning the username and password is requested and if the "remember" field is checked you don't have to login every time (maybe once a month then). What's the best way to do that? A session on the Server or saving username and password local? If I make a HTTP-Request where Session Data is saved, is it still available or active when I make a HTTP-Request on the same server later? (like for getting the chat content, or something else?)
I searched the internet, but didn't find something useful. If someone could tell me how to do that, or post a link or something that could help..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server identifies a client through a token (e.g. session cookie). With each HTTP request, session cookie is sent to the server and server knows that request is coming from a client who has authenticated before.

The time span of this authentication is of course equal to the validity of the token (cookie in this case). The token can be invalidated on either client or server. You may require special mechanism for keeping sessions valid for month. Defaults are usually like half an hour.

Second option of storing password is more of a security decision. If you store user credentials, then you have to make sure that you do it in a secure manner.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. That's good to know, in WebApps for example all Sessions are reseted after relaunching the WebApp. As I only need password and Email, this is the best way I think. Then I only have to config the server sessions that they will be saved for a long time..

Comment: Glad it helped. Just one more point: Facebook may not be keeping you logged in for a month. The authentication might be renewed every time you visit the site (say every other day).

Comment: Okay. I have another little question: I am a bit confused now, first I forgot to change localization from English to German, now it always loads an old UIView which doesn't exist. Although I deleted the project folder a few times and created a new one. There is still the App like it was before.

Comment: When I change the Simulator to german it shows the correct one, but only on English it shows an old app, although I deleted english localization in the project settings

Comment: But this is a problem of the simulator I think. But the session is not anymore available after closing the app, and restarting it. Is there a way to prevent the session of being deleted.

Comment: Okay I did it now by resetting the Session cookie (`setcookie("PHPSESSID", session_id(), time()+2678400);` in PHP).

Answer (score 1):

If the user checks the save password field you could save the password to NSUserDefaults.
Although that's not good for encryption, it works. You should also use some type of encoding (SHA-1). You could make it aks for your password after say 10. To do that you would want a data store. You would load it into an int and then you can simply do something like `runTime = runTime + 1;` and if it get to ten purge the password data